# SetActive not recognized?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So yeah, I'm trying to make a little game on unity, creating a Pause Menu and when I create a variable with a `GameObject`, I can't use `SetActive`, it basically says that `SetActive` is not recognized.

Here's the code :

```
bool IsPaused;
GameObject[] Pause_Menu;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    IsPaused = false;
    Pause_Menu = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Pause_Menu");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Pause_Menu.SetActive(IsPaused);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("escape"))
    {
        IsPaused = true;
    }
    if ((Input.GetKeyDown("escape")) && (IsPaused = true))
    {
        IsPaused = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're grabbing an array of objects when you use `FindGameObjectsWithTag`.

What you probably want is this:

```
bool IsPaused;
GameObject Pause_Menu;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start ( )
{
    IsPaused = false;
    Pause_Menu = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ( "Pause_Menu" );
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ( )
{
    Pause_Menu.SetActive ( IsPaused );

    if ( Input.GetKeyDown ( "escape" ) )
    {
        IsPaused = true;
    }
    if ( ( Input.GetKeyDown ( "escape" ) ) && ( IsPaused = true ) )
    {
        IsPaused = false;
    }
}
```

Define Pause_Menu as a single GameObject, not an array of GameObjects, and change `FindGameObjectsWithTag` to `FindGameObjectWithTag` (drop the 's'). Or even the shorter version `FindWithTag` as in:

```
Pause_Menu = GameObject.FindWithTag ( "Pause_Menu" );
```

Here's the Unity Docs for [FindWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html).

Comment: alright thanks ! but what if I want to disable all the GameObjects with this tag at once ?

Comment: This isn't answering your question directly, but, would it make sense in your hierarchy to simply `SetActive (true/false)` a parent object to turn the whole set of menu items on and off as a group?

Comment: @LeFauconQC if this answered your question, mark it as answered, and draw a line under it. Cheers.